# get list of origin urls from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I need to only allow a list of sites to embed our site.

```
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String requestReferer = request.getHeader("Referer");

    for (String s : whiteList) {
        if (requestReferer.toLowerCase().contains(s))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am getting the "Referer" from the request header which gives the complete URL of the origin: http://somesite.com/something/something

The above code works fine. However, is there a way to just get the host name from the HttpServletRequest object rather than using "Referer"?
I mean is there a way to just get "somesite.com" from the HttpServletRequest object.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` and `ServletRequest.getRemoteHost()` to obtain information about the client.

The Javadoc of `getRemoteHost` says:

> Returns the fully qualified name of the client or the last proxy that
>   sent the request. If the engine cannot or chooses not to resolve the
>   hostname (to improve performance), this method returns the
>   dotted-string form of the IP address. For HTTP servlets, same as the
>   value of the CGI variable REMOTE_HOST.

Comment: OP want to extract host from referrer, not to figure out own host.